# Delay return from function using promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'd like to run the function that consists of:
if condition is solved
1)add class
2)sleep 4 sec then remove class
3)then stop running function using return.

```
    function sleep(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    })
  }
    function playGame() {
    if (counter === 3) {
        Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            message.classList.add('winner');
            sleep(2500).then(function () {
                message.classList.remove('winner');
            });
        });
        return;
      }
    ...
   }
```

If I run this code, function returning immediately of course. How do I add return to the promise chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(function () {
    message.classList.add('winner');
})
.then(sleep(2500))
.then(function() {
    message.classList.remove('winner');
});
```

This should be self-explanatory. Feel free to ask more questions as needed.

**EDIT** : Oooops it seems that I answered this one too quickly. You can never postpone a "return" statement in javascript. In your case, your code, or mine executes immediately, and the `return` of the enclosing function is called immediately, and the execution goes back to the event loop. *Then*, the first *then()* of the promise is called, etc...

Since you can't postpone the return of the function, you use callbacks, or better, Promises, to chain events:

```
function playGame() {
    return Promise.resolve()  // note the return !
    .then(function () {
        message.classList.add('winner');
    })
    .then(sleep(2500))
    .then(function() {
        message.classList.remove('winner');
    });
}

...then

playGame()
.then(function() {
    // this code is called after playGame's Promise has been executed
});

// this code is called when playGame ends, ie immediately, and before any promises code
```

To put it differently: once you begin to have asynchronous code (through callbacks or promises), every further code needs to be driven by promises, too.

Comment: You 've forgotten to add return in the end after promise. in my opinion this would be more clear. Thanks It seems it works)

Comment: If it's not hard you may write a few sentences with explanation, why my case didn't work

Comment: answer modified